# Why there is no login/password for Ubuntu One under System->Preferences?

Tags: ubuntu-one

What type of authentication Ubuntu One uses? Why there is no Login/Password fields under System->Preferences->Ubuntu One entry?

Is current U1 auth based on cookies or something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ubuntu One is storing your credential inside Gnome Keyring Manager. You can access this manager from the `System` -> `Preferences` menu (or in older Ubuntu release from the Applications -> Accessories) choose the application named `Passwords and Encryption Keys`.

You can see that your Ubuntu One credentials are stored there.

[image]

Note that this keyring manager is encrypted, it's a safe store. But it is unlock upon login, so that's why you don't need to enter your Ubuntu One credentials.

Answer (score 0):

It's really worth installing this little indicator-applet to see what Ubuntu One is doing.  It's no dropbox, not by a long shot, but I find it helps demystify what on earth U1 is up to at any given moment :
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/10/ubuntu-one-indicator-applet-puts-sync-status-back-into-view/

Sadly, this proposed upgrade to the Ubuntu One client didn't appear the make the cut for 10.10 :
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/07/the-ubuntu-one-control-panel-beauty-in-simplicity/

Comment: I'm not sure this is useful. Yeah for us geeks - we're quite control freaks - we like to see what's going on ;-) But for a normal user point of view it should be: "it just works"! Mozilla is doing the same with Firefox Sync in Firefox 4 at the moment. Chrome/Chromium do also the same. When it works, you don't need to verify it. However, from a marketing point of view, this is an idea! At least people feel that they have something special. Think about the On/Off buttons for ABS, ESP, etc. or even the strange red break on Porsche car. It's marketing, not ergonomics behind that.

Comment: The second link looks promising, I would like to have sth like this on my Ubuntu intsallation.